# Trying to join two tables via subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Current query below

```
    select
      x.OVERALL_ID,
      extract(year from y.tsdate) as year,
      extract(month from y.tsdate) as month,
      round(sum(y.grossamount),2) as "labour cost",
      sum(y.reg)+sum(y.ot) as "labour hours"
    from
    (
    select OVERALL_ID,
          BOAT_NAME
    from TV_VESSEL_VISIT
      group by OVERALL_ID,VESSEL_NAME
      order by OVERALL_ID, VESSEL_NAME
    ) as x
    inner join
    (
    select *
    from TRANS
    where ratedesc = 'Labour'
      and opsdesc = 'Ops'
      and ACTDESC = 'Nature of Job'
      and terminal = 'UKN'
      and reconciled = 'Y'
      and TSDATE between '20-JAN-01' and '20-JAN-31'
    ) as y on x.BOAT_NAME = y.BOATNAME

      group by OVERALL_ID, extract(year from tsdate), extract(month from tsdate)
      order by OVERALL_ID, extract(year from tsdate), extract(month from tsdate);
```

Desired result is OVERALL_ID's labour cost/hours grouped into year and month

Currently getting the below error

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 14 Column: 3
```

Trying to follow this link https://www.geeksengine.com/database/subquery/subquery-in-join-operation.php

Comment: the "ORA-00933" identifies you are using Oracle. Please use this tag because "sql" is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

If using subqueries DO NOT use ORDER BY inside those subqueries. There is no good purpose to the ordering, it just isn't required.

Try this:

```
SELECT
       x.OVERALL_ID
     , extract(year FROM y.tsdate) AS year
     , extract(month FROM y.tsdate) AS month
     , round(sum(y.grossamount), 2) AS "labour cost"
     , sum(y.reg) + sum(y.ot) AS "labour hours"
FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT
            OVERALL_ID
          , BOAT_NAME
         FROM TV_VESSEL_VISIT
     ) x
INNER JOIN (
         SELECT *
         FROM TRANS
         WHERE ratedesc = 'Labour'
          AND opsdesc = 'Ops'
          AND ACTDESC = 'Nature of Job'
          AND terminal = 'UKN'
          AND reconciled = 'Y'
          AND TSDATE >= to_date('2020-01-01','yyy-mm-dd') AND TSDATE < to_date('2020-02-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
     ) y ON x.BOAT_NAME = y.BOATNAME
GROUP BY
       OVERALL_ID
     , extract(year FROM tsdate)
     , extract(month FROM tsdate)
ORDER BY
       OVERALL_ID
     , extract(year FROM tsdate)
     , extract(month FROM tsdate)
;
```

Notes: I have removed the unwanted ORDER BY in the upper subquery, and changed this to use SELECT DISTINCT (it will produce the same result as the previous group by subquery). Also I have changed the syntax used for the date range. Please avoid using 2 digit year references, always use the full year. Additionally I always recommend avoiding the use of `between` for date ranges it is far more predictable to use the combination of `>=` with `<` as you see above. Plus I have used `to_date()` so it is clear what dates I am using for the date range - which will give you every row of data relevant to January 2020.

The previous `between` syntax could possibly miss a whole day's data

Answer (score 1):

Orable allows `AS` when declaring a column alias, but does not allow it for a table alias. The subquery alias is the same case as table alias. try `) x` instead of `) as x`, and the same thing for `y`. This is one of the syntax errors that causes ORA-00933.

Comment: Very good. So easy to overlook. Wish Oracle didn't have this restriction!